# KVM Installation on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: kvm-virtualization, 17.10

I have gone through [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation).

But I am getting following error when adding user to group.

```
adduser: The group `libvirtd' does not exist.
```

This worked perfectly in *16.04*.

Is there anything missing in *Ubuntu 17.10*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem following the guide you've mentioned above.

The problem is - that group is called `libvirt` and NOT `libvirtd`.

You should already be part of it (run `groups` to check), so just logout and login back.

To check if it's ok run `virsh -c qemu:///system list` **WITHOUT** sudo.

[More info](https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Failed_to_connect_to_the_hypervisor)

The answer was found [here](https://github.com/chouseknecht/minishift-up-role/issues/2):

> According to [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/libvirt.html) ubuntu help, the correct group name is libvirt.

Comment: Somebody with edit permission should update and fix the instructions for the community wiki for Ubuntu 17.10 After the installation the user is already a member of `libvirt` (no d) in Ubuntu 17.10:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation#Add_Users_to_Groups

Answer (score 1):

In recent releases (>= Ubuntu Yakkety) the user group libvirtd was renamed to libvirt. An upgraded system gets a new libvirt group with the same gid as the libvirtd group to match that.

Do this Bash script to resolve it.

```
cat /etc/group | grep "libvirt"   
sudo adduser root libvirt
sudo adduser ubuntu libvirt
sudo adduser root libvirtd       # legacy
sudo adduser ubuntu libvirtd     # legacy
cat /etc/group | grep "libvirt"
sudo systemctl restart libvirtd
sudo systemctl status libvirtd
```

Comment: If you have more issues installing Ubuntu 17.10 in a VM using libvirt/KVM/QEMU then read this checklist http://rolf.huijbrechts.be/vm-ubuntu1710desktop-blog/